# How can you find the source for an "onevent" handler in HTML, without the event listeners panel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at an element that has several event handlers added to it the old-fashioned way--

```
<input onblur="doSomething()" onkeyup="doSomethingElse()">
```

When I check the event listeners panel in the inspector, it is entirely empty.

Is there a way to find the code for these in the page's source besides manually ctrl+f'ing for the function names?

Comment: This is a bug in current version of Chrome https://crbug.com/700876 fixed in v60. You can install Chrome canary separately or use a workaround: click a node, run `getEventListeners($0)` in the console.

Comment: is there a chance to make a text-based search within the funcion's names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Chrome 70. Here's a screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing the registered event handlers for the selected input element,

[image]

And to find the source code for those function, just copy-paste the function name in the console, and press enter - you'll get the source code for those function.

[image]

Or, you can do a quick search by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F, which will open up the search panel. Now, check the regular expression box and type "function\s*doSomething\s*\(" and press Enter. This will take you directly to the function definition.

[image]

Comment: Damn, the answer I'd been waiting for all along swoops in at the last second.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the toString method in your console:

```
doSomething.toString()
```

Or you could find it via the debugger:

```
function findMyCode(element){
    debugger
    element.onblur.call(element);
}
findMyCode(document.getElementById('idOfYourInput'));
```

Then step into the function call.